# Adding timestamps in the journal file?

Tags: spss

I'm wondering if it's possible to add timestamps to the journal file?

It appears that a date & time are recorded when SPSS is started, but if you have the program open for longer periods of time (i.e. days) it doesn't break it up if the program isn't closed.

Having timestamps would make it much easier to find what I'm looking for the times I look back to find things.

This is what I use to insert timestamps into my output:

```
HOST COMMAND=['echo %time%'].
```

However the journal file only shows the syntax.

Comment: Why not have other more distinctive markers than time? i.e. "/* Start of Job1 Syntax */. " or something along those lines? And a whole lot easier to implment then something over complicated? Just a thought.

Comment: The way I work with syntax already gives me something similar to that (in terms of file naming conventions, etc.). Part of the reason I need date & time is I also occassionally use it to account for task & time; i.e. I need to know how much time I spent on a particular task.

Answer (score 1):

The journal file is kept flushed and closed by Statistics, so you can probably write to it from another process.  I don't think the suggestion above will work, because it will write the code but not the output to the journal.  However, using Python you could do something like this.

begin program.
import time
open(r"full path to your journal file", "a").write("* " + time.asctime() + "\n")
end program

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why it shouldn't work, unless you are not using a windows operating system.

On Unix-like system like Linux or Mac which run the bash (shell) you would rather use

`HOST COMMAND =['date'].`

If you have the Python extension installed you could also use Python code to to print the date and time (which would be a platform independent solution).

```
BEGIN PROGRAM.
import time
print time.ctime()
END PROGRAM.
```